# Subscribe to Knowledge articles or categories

Tags: knowledge, data-category, categories

Is it possible to allow users to subscribe to new knowledge content based on data categories? I'd like users to be able to subscribe to their preferred data categories so that they can receive email alerts when new knowledge content is added to the category.

If this isn't available using standard functionality, I'm hoping others might have suggestions for how to accomplish this through customization.

Comment: I've just spent quite a while looking for a way to do this too. There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gprvAAA) for similar functionality, to send notifications to external users. But it looks like this can only be done using code. If I end up developing a solution, I'll share it here..

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of users the internal users and the external users.

I recommend you to go through these two links.

### This link is about what to do once you have enabled Knowledge.

[You’ve Implemented Salesforce Knowledge – What Now?](http://www.revolutiongroup.com/youve-implemented-salesforce-knowledge-what-now/)

### This link is to the Knowledge implementation guide.

[Salesforce Knowlegde implementation guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/17/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_implementation_guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but perhaps my original question was unclear. I'm aware of the various user types, but I'm wondering if users can subscribe to email alerts when new content is added. I've edited my question to be more specific.